# Validate: remove custom success message when error occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery validate to use a remote call to check if a username exists. Like this:

```
remote: {
    url: "MyUrl",
    type: "GET",
    complete: function (data) {
        // Return success message if applicable
        if (data.responseText == "true")
        {
            $("#divUserNameAvailable").show();
        }
    }
}
```

But if I stay in the field and force a validation error, the message stays.

[image]

Here is the full validation:

```
if ($("#CreateAccountForm").length) {
    $("#CreateAccountForm").validate({
        rules: {
            UserName: {
                required: true,
                rangelength: [6, 20],
                usernameFilter: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "MyUrl",
                    type: "GET",
                    complete: function (data) {
                        // Return success message if applicable
                        if (data.responseText == "true")
                        {
                            $("#divUserNameAvailable").show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        messages: {

            UserName: {
                remote: "This username is not available. Please enter a new username.",
                required: "Please enter your username.",
                rangelength: "Usernames must be between 6 and 20 characters in length and may not use any special characters such as \\ / + {{ }} [ ] | = , * ? ; : < > @."
            },

        },

        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

I try to hide the DIV in the `errorPlacement`, but nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a successful call, then hide the error `<div>`:

```
remote: {
    url: "MyUrl",
    type: "GET",
    complete: function (data) {
        // Return success message if applicable
        if (data.responseText == "true")
        {
            $("#divUserNameAvailable").show();
            // Hide the error div. Replace the `that_error_div_selector` with right selector.
            $(that_error_div_selector).hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but what for other validations (required, etc.)? My issue is if it is initially successful, then errors occur in the field after.

Comment: @DaveBrock This is for that particular validation only right?

Comment: @DaveBrock This code would clear the error message only for that particular `field`. If you could show me a working snippet, may be I can help you further.

Comment: I added the entire validation rules for the field. Say, I get a success then delete a few spaces I see the screenshot I posted above.

Comment: I edited my original post, it says it has to be peer-reviewed first. Basically, if I have "required: true" and it occurs after I get the success message, I am unable to hide the success message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116595/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-dave-brock).